Place a figure and table side by side and aligned at the top in a figure float
I'm using LyX 2.3.8 and would like to place a small table (4 rows, 2 columns) and a related figure side by side in a float. I started by inserting a figure float into my document, and then inserted a figure (.png file) and a table immediately following it into the float. I set the figure width to 8 cm to leave plenty of space for the table. But when I export to pdf, the top of the table and the top of the figure are not aligned - the table appears to the right of the figure, but with its top roughly level with the bottom of the figure. How can I position the two in one float with their tops aligned?
Sincerely and with many thanks in advance
Thomas Philips
The LyX code looks crazy, and I honestly don't understand it:
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\noindent
\align center
\begin_inset Box Frameless
position "b"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "45col%"
special "none"
height "8cm"
height_special "none"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\noindent
\align center
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename Plots/Kurtosis Minimization.png
    scale 50

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Projections onto the kurtosis minimizing vector
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset space \hspace*{\fill}
\end_inset


\begin_inset Box Boxed
position "b"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "45col%"
special "none"
height "8cm"
height_special "none"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\noindent
\align center
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="5" columns="2">
<features booktabs="true" tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Projection Vector
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Sepal.Length
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none
0.988068380
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Sepal.Width
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none
0.114840009
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Petal.Length
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none
-0.102380058
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Petal.Width
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none
0.007139457
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
The kurtosis minimizing projection vector
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout


Welcome to TeX.SE, please post your code as MWE for better understanding

Welcome,kindly share your MWE and an image of what you desire to achieve.Thanks

Please mark LyX code blocks using the 4 space indent (three backticks do sometimes not work). I've edited your question and done it using mouse select + ctrl-k.

@JohnKormylo You mean the second example in my answer. ;-)

A LaTeX suggestion would be:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \vspace{0pt}% Important!
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{\linewidth-8cm}}
    \raggedleft
    \vspace{0pt}% Important
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      left & right \\\midrule
      2 & 2 \\
      3 & 3 \\
      4 & 4 \\
      5 & 5 \\
      6 & 6 \\
      7 & 7 \\
      final & final \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Figure and table side-by-side, top-aligned}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

or:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \adjincludegraphics[width=8cm,valign=t]{example-image}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lr}% optional argument important!
    left & right \\\midrule
    2 & 2 \\
    3 & 3 \\
    4 & 4 \\
    5 & 5 \\
    6 & 6 \\
    7 & 7 \\
    final & final \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Figure and table side-by-side, top-aligned}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Both with the result:

Or:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht\strutbox-\totalheight}}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lr}
      left & right \\\midrule
      2 & 2 \\
      3 & 3 \\
      4 & 4 \\
      5 & 5 \\
      6 & 6 \\
      7 & 7 \\
      final & final \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Figure and table side-by-side, top-aligned}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

with a similar bot not identical result:

But because I'm not using LyX and you've not shown a LyX MWE of what you already have and that could be used to search for adaptions, I don't know how to realize the same with the LyX interface to LaTeX.

The LyX code looks crazy, and I honestly don't understand it. I tried pasting it in here and it is too long by 3800 characters, so i added it to my original post. I can't even figure out how to make a minimal example. I'll try your suggestion, and if it works, great and if not, I'll just separate the two.

Here is a paracol solution. Note that this solution doesn't actually float.
MWE stolen from cabohah's solution.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}% for figure/table bottom/top
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*

\begin{document}
\setcolumnwidth{8cm}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      left & right \\\midrule
      2 & 2 \\
      3 & 3 \\
      4 & 4 \\
      5 & 5 \\
      6 & 6 \\
      7 & 7 \\
      final & final \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


+1 Creative. ;-)

Thank you both - I entered this code in a box (Ctrl +L) and edited it. Your solution works perfectly, though I have a few questions:

What role does \globalcounter* play?
I added labels (e.g. \label{fig:KurtosisMinProjections}) just below the captions (e.g. \caption{Projections on to the kurtosis minimizing vector}, and these work perfectly, but I have to do the insertion manually - the Insert label tool doesn't work and they appear as broken references wherever I insert them, but they do compile correctly.
How can I make the table style formal (it's a right-clickable option in LyX)


Got the table formatted correctly - added \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule. Also used \hphantom{} to clean up spacing. Thanks a million. I couldn't have done this without your help.

Normally paracol replaces the counters in the columns to allow duplicate sections, figures etc.  \globalcounter* turns that off.
